# Passing parameters to SSIS Execute process task

Tags: command-line, ssis, command-prompt

I am using SSIS 2012..

i want to execute a exe file with two variable parameters

Executable: C:\temp\MyExe.exe

Parameter1: **ABCD** ---------- type is string

Parameter2: **1234** ---------- type is string

In dos it looks like this

**c:\temp>MyExe.exe "ABCD" "1234"**

This will executes fine.

Now I do not know what to place here when I want to use the Execute Process Task in SSIS.

[image]

Comment: Try to put `WorkingDirectory` as `C:\temp` and `executable` as `MyExe.exe` . Also put a variable in `StandardErrorVariable` to catch the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, I had a damn space after the MyExe.exe