# How execute an exe file with dynamic parameters within a loop

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a database table with 20 columns and 40 rows. In the third column is an identifier that is unique.

I have a .exe written in VB.NET that connects to a datasource and downloads a dataset depending on the identifier. So this VB.NET programm needs an input parameter.

Now I want SSIS to loop over the rows and execute the .exe 40 times (for each identifier). I have found the possibility to do this with a static variable in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157852/passing-parameters-to-ssis-execute-process-task) but I just can not complete the task to do this with my identifiers.

Could anyone help me here?

Comment: Don't know the syntax, but I bet this can be done with a script transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an SSIS variable of User::MyParameter

In your Foreach Loop, you'd want to get the set of values from your source or whatever and assign that to User::MyParameter. Once that is looking as expected (via temporary Script task or something), then connect it up to the Execute Process Task.

In the `Execute Process Task`, you will connect User::MyParameter to the StandardInputVariable property in the editor.

[image: Execute Process Task]